# I’m returning a package but seller gave me the name of so many places I’m not sure what is the street/city name since they also named a town/village

Tags: translation

China Guangdong Province Dongguan Fenggang Town 1st Floor, Building A, Lane 28, Hongshi Road, Yantian Village
CN 523690 Dongguan Guangdong Province
[image: mailing site]

Answer (score 1):

(China) (Guangdong Province) (Dongguan) (Fenggang Town) (1st Floor, Building A, Lane 28, Hongshi Road, Yantian Village) (CN 523690) (Dongguan) (Guangdong Province)

Dongguan is the city.

This is the address.

(1st Floor, Building A, Lane 28, Hongshi Road, Yantian Village)